# Animate ParametricFuction in manim

Tags: manim

I am using manim community and I am trying to slightly edit [this example](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.graphing.functions.ParametricFunction.html#plotparametricfunction) so that the function plotting takes 2 secs. Replacing the last line with:

```
self.play(func.animate, run_time=2)
```

throws an error: 'TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object"

Do you know what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As describe here [Unable to fill color in manim with parametric curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141154/unable-to-fill-color-in-manim-with-parametric-curve),

you cannot define the function `func` as class member. Instead you need to define outside of the class scope. The following example works as expected.

```
from manim import *

def func(t):
    return np.array((np.sin(2 * t), np.sin(3 * t), 0))


class ExampleFunctionGraph(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        f = ParametricFunction(
            func, t_range=np.array([0, TAU]), fill_opacity=0
        ).set_color(RED)
        self.play(Create(f, run_time=8, rate_func=linear))
        self.wait()
```