# Unable to fill color in manim with parametric curve

Tags: python-3.x, manim

I am trying to create a [rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics)). I am able to complete it with the following code, but for some reason, I am unable to fill the rose with color. As you can see, I am using set_fill() method to fill the color with BLUE.But somehow, no fill is received at my end.
I am unable to solve this problem.

```
from manim import *
import numpy as np

class Rose(Scene):
     

        def func(self, t):

            a, k = 2, 10
            x = a*np.cos(k*t)*np.cos(t)
            y = a*np.cos(k*t)*np.sin(t)
            return np.array((x, y, 0))


        def construct(self):
            func = CurvesAsSubmobjects(ParametricFunction(self.func, 
                                        t_range=np.array([0, TAU])))
            func = func.set_color(BLUE).set_stroke(width=1).set_fill(BLUE,opacity=0.5)
            self.play(Create(func.scale(1)), run_time=8)
            self.wait(1)
```

I am getting an output but the rose is not filled with the BLUE color. Thanks for the help.
Manim version: v0.17.3 and python 3.11

Comment: Tip: when you use `from manim import *`, `numpy` is already imported as `np`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the use of `CurvesAsSubmobjects()`. This class divides the continuous curve generated by `ParametricFunction()` into a ton (around 600 actually) tiny objects.

When you set the fill color, you are setting it for each of these tiny objects, not for the "global" curve. Each of these tiny objects is indeed so thin, that its area is zero and the fill color cannot be seen.

So the solution is to remove the `CurvesAsSubmobjects()` call. Why did you include it? My guess is that you did that to avoid a mysterious exception that you'll get otherwise:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

This error happens if you try to animate directly the creation of the `ParametricFunction`, and disappears if you use `CurvesAsSubmobjects()`.

However, the true cause of that exception is that the function you are passing to `ParametricFunction()` is a method of the `Scene`, because you defined it so:

```py
class Rose(Scene):
        def func(self, t):
            a, k = 2, 10
            x = a*np.cos(k*t)*np.cos(t)
            y = a*np.cos(k*t)*np.sin(t)
            return np.array((x, y, 0))
```

So, when you call:

```
ParametricFunction(self.func, t_range=np.array([0, TAU]))
```

you are passing a method which is part of the Scene. This causes problems when internally Manim tries to perform deepcopies of the object (which happens during animations). The problem is that, due to the way you defined the function, it has to deepcopy also the Scene, and this cannot be done because the scene contains a logger. The reason is very technical and obscure.

But you don't need to have `func()` has a method of the scene. It can be an external function, or even an internal function defined inside `construct()` (this does not makes it a method, because it has not relation with `self`).

So the solution to your problem is:

1. Define `func()` so that it is not a method of the Scene
2. Do not use `CurvesAsSubmobjects()`

I.e: your code should be:

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        def f(t):
            a, k = 2, 10
            x = a*np.cos(k*t)*np.cos(t)
            y = a*np.cos(k*t)*np.sin(t)
            return np.array((x, y, 0))
        func = ParametricFunction(f, t_range=np.array([0, TAU, 0.1]))
        func = func.set_color(BLUE).set_stroke(width=1).set_fill(BLUE,opacity=0.5)
        self.play(Create(func, run_time=8, rate_func=linear))
        self.wait()
```

This works, but perhaps not how you desired:

[image: Creation]

I think that you wanted to use `Write()` instead of `Create()`, since `Write()` draws first the contour and then fades in the filling:

[image: Write]

### Update

`Create()` can also work nicely if you start the drawing at the center of the rose, instead of at one extreme. You can do so by adding `PI/2` to the cos() component:

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        def f(t):
            a, k = 2, 10
            x = a*np.cos(k*t+PI/2)*np.cos(t)
            y = a*np.cos(k*t+PI/2)*np.sin(t)
            return np.array((x, y, 0))
        func = ParametricFunction(f, t_range=np.array([0, TAU, 0.1]))
        func = func.set_color(BLUE).set_stroke(width=1).set_fill(BLUE, opacity=0.5)
        self.play(Create(func, run_time=8, rate_func=linear))
        self.wait()
```

Results in:

[image: Another version]

Comment: Thanks a lot, one question how did you know so much about it. I am trying hard to learn this as well, but the amount of information that you presented is really good. Are there any resources apart from docs that you know of? manim doc is awesome however sometimes it's good to have different examples to concrete the concepts, that's whu I am asking. Thank you so much

Comment: I use the docs, the youtube material, and the discord channel. And when all this fails, my last resource is the source code. I use VSCode, set a breakpoint in a line, and use the debugger to dive into the details, step by step. It is also useful to let the program crash and use the debugger to see the line which caused the problem, and you have all the call frames to see from where it was called, the values of the variables at that point, and so on.